# Asp.Net Core 2.1 - routes.MapRoute Display the URL in Browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there any way that the Browser display the URL in every case?

In my given example it works as I want but not for the default route, for default route the displayed URL is only e.g. https://localhost:44383/.

When I click on Home/About, the display shows correct https://localhost:44383/Home/About.

Whenever i click on the index the browser display only https://localhost:44383/
and it should display https://localhost:44383/Home/Index.... ?

Hope you can help?

In `"public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)"`

this is my only route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: If you add `[RoutePrefix("Home")]` attribute above your HomeController, does it show `/Home/Index` in your URL?

You may have to set the [Route] attribute for your Index and for each of your other actions e.g.[Route("About")], etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution - a little bit tricky but it works:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();


            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == "/")
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("Home/Index", true);
                }
                await next();
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Index",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
```